# problem in showing all images from folder python

Tags: python

I want to show all images from a folder through python but got this error -

```
File "<tokenize>", line 18
    imagesList = listdir(path) IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

code:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):

imagesList = listdir(path)
loadedImages = []
for image in imagesList:
    img = PImage.open(path + image)
    loadedImages.append(img)

return loadedImages

path = "CATS_DOGS/train/CAT/"
 imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an indentation issue, just as the error says so.

This is how it should be:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):
   imagesList = listdir(path)
   loadedImages = []
   for image in imagesList:
      img = PImage.open(path + image)
      loadedImages.append(img)
      img.close()
   return loadedImages

path = "CATS_DOGS/train/CAT/"
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
   img.show()
```

Comment: it creates OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'CATS_DOGS/train/CAT/cat.1.jpg'

Comment: I've edited the code and added a close op, please try now.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in `python` the syntax is to use indents (tab), instead the use of `{ }` in other languages (like java, c# js, etc.), in order to enter an inner scope.

So just use indent in all your function code, which will define your code **inside** the function `loadImages`:

```
def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)

    return loadedImages

path = "CATS_DOGS/train/CAT/"
imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
img.show()
```

Plus, the line `imgs = loadImages(path)` was with 1 space indent, which may cause the same problem again.

Comment: thank you for sharing.  imgs = loadImages(path)  this line gives  OSError: cannot identify image file 'CATS_DOGS/train/CAT/Thumbs.db'

Comment: clearly that file isn't an image. if you just want to blindly open every file with he assumption it's an image, at least put a try ... except in there